# How do check for keyboard input while continuing to update and draw game items

Tags: c++, input, allegro5

I am using Allegro and C++ to develop a basic game. What I found is that the common answer for taking in keyboard input is the line

```
al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &ev);
```

however, what I don't like about it is that it causes your program to **wait** for input. If the position of a meteor needs to be continuously updated, then I don't want my keyboard listening to stop its movement.

In my experience with XNA, I would simply update what the keyboard looked like each tick and ask if a key was pressed. What method might I use to continue updating and drawing my game while still checking input similar to how XNA handled it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `al_wait_for_event`, you should be using `al_get_next_event` in a loop until it returns false. It returns immediately, and returns false once there's no more events. (Also look at `al_is_event_queue_empty` and `al_peek_next_event`, which you might find useful.)

Once you've run out of events, update your game logic, draw the frame, and start all over again. (This is formally knows as the "game loop".)

Answer (score 1):

Most people set up an event loop controlled by a timer:

```
ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = al_create_timer(1 / 60.0);
al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
// register keyboard, other sources
```

Now when you wait for an event, you'll get a timer tick every 1/60th of a second, which you can react to accordingly and update a frame of logic.

Answer (score 0):

Allegro's [`al_get_keyboard_state`](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/5.0.9/keyboard.html#al_get_keyboard_state) does just that: It returns the current state of the keyboard at the time of the call.